# Sandbox "Sorry — your last action could not be completed"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

My site was working fine with PayPal's sandbox, and then all of a sudden it stopped.

Now I get the wonderful error `Sandbox "Sorry — your last action could not be completed"`

This is my HTML:

```
<body onload="document.Paypal.submit();">
    <!-- item_number should get passed back -->
    <form name="Paypal" method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com cgi-bin/webscr" id="Paypal">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTkyNTEyNzc0NGRk0LKGvSMTla6LgHpbOsdk7iC0iXE=" />
</div>

<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWCALKhatPArLPtrsEAreImG4CweeH+AkCgMPhowcC+NaM4gQC+Y2VqwoCouzSnwEVXI9UvQxqI2UcdQ4SmcSWqfEZNw==" />
</div>

        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />         

        <!-- The following is for itemized PayPal data instead of the aggregated version -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="LEADING SKILLS 4/10/2012 6:00 PM Section: Members " />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="250.00" />
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="2" />

        <input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="7.00" />

        <input type="hidden" name="tax_cart" value="35.00" />

        <!-- STANDARD DATA -->
        <input name="business" type="hidden" id="business" value="paypal@rockclimbing.venueblue.com" />

        <input name="invoice" type="hidden" id="invoice" value="TS-1E8B59A0-B" />
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" /> 
        <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" id="currency_code" value="USD" />
        <input name="shipCountry" type="hidden" id="shipCountry" />
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://rockclimbing.venueblue.com/Gateway/paypal/Complete.aspx?id=db86c0bf-beb8-4e37-b495-bed1d3e7e6f3" />
        <input name="cancel_returnUrl" type="hidden" id="cancel_returnUrl" value="http://rockclimbing.venueblue.com/ShoppingCart.aspx" />


        <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="How did you hear about us?" />
        <input name="custom" type="hidden" id="custom" value="db86c0bf-beb8-4e37-b495-bed1d3e7e6f3" />          
        <input name="notify_url" type="hidden" id="notify_url" value="http://rockclimbing.venueblue.com/Gateway/Paypal/IPN.aspx" />         

  <input type="submit" value="Submit Payment Info" style="display:none;" />

  Processing Order....

    </form>
</body>
```

Anyone have a clue what happened?

Answer (score 3):

Well i had the same thing today earlier, I thought i screwed smth up. I was using Opera, then changed to FireFox and there was no such error. then i deleted Browsing history, cookies, cash, everything and the problem disapeared in opera. maybe you could try that too.

Comment: Worked for me. While doing sandbox tests I need to switch between buyer an facilitator accounts. I had the error because I was still logged in with a different account.